# Logging Events in a Windows Service Program

Tags: c#, events, service, logging

I have created a Windows service program and I want my error to strictly be written to the Windows eventLog. So I followed these steps from code project article:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/simplewindowsservice.aspx

But I don't see any of the custom log messages I wrote in the event logs created in the event viewer window when I start or stop the service. 
Also how do I specify whether the message was due to an error or is just info?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

First, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.aspx) is your friend. Make sure you check out the link, as there are some potential gotchas worth knowing.

Essentially, you create an EventLog object:

```
this.ServiceName = "MyService";
this.EventLog = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();
this.EventLog.Source = this.ServiceName;
this.EventLog.Log = "Application";
```

You also need to create a source, if the above source doesn't exist:

```
((ISupportInitialize)(this.EventLog)).BeginInit();
if (!EventLog.SourceExists(this.EventLog.Source))
{
    EventLog.CreateEventSource(this.EventLog.Source, this.EventLog.Log);
}
((ISupportInitialize)(this.EventLog)).EndInit();
```

and then simply use it:

```
this.EventLog.WriteEntry("My Eventlog message.", EventLogEntryType.Information);
```

it's actually pretty simple.

Comment: Note that you will need to have correct permissions to actually create the log.  Otherwise you will get an exception (as of at least Windows Server 2003)

Comment: Definitely, and that is clearly noted in the MSDN documentation.

Comment: @alphadogg the property of EventLog of a ServiceBase is readonly. The code is wrong. By default, .NET based Windows Service will write the event log as "Application", so you don't need to specifiy it manually.

Comment: Could you please explain why `ISupportInitialize` is used in your code?  That is, why do you need to enclose the code within a BeginInit()/EndInit() pair? Thank you.

Comment: Anyone know where we can find/view this log?

Comment: You can read the logs using the Event Viewer app (it will show under Windows Logs > Application).

Answer (score 29):

I finally got this to work by combining various StackOverflow answers and from MSDN.

First include the following namespaces

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
```

Then setup logging in your constructor

```
    public UserService1() 
    {
        //Setup Service
        this.ServiceName = "MyService2";
        this.CanStop = true;
        this.CanPauseAndContinue = true;

        //Setup logging
        this.AutoLog = false;

        ((ISupportInitialize) this.EventLog).BeginInit();
        if (!EventLog.SourceExists(this.ServiceName))
        {
            EventLog.CreateEventSource(this.ServiceName, "Application");
        }
        ((ISupportInitialize) this.EventLog).EndInit();

        this.EventLog.Source = this.ServiceName;
        this.EventLog.Log = "Application";
    }
```

Use as follows:

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        base.OnStart(args);

        this.EventLog.WriteEntry("In OnStart");
    }
```