# NLog not working from Windows Service hosted WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services, nlog

I have a WCF service with NLog logging in C#. This service references 3 class libraries. Every projects uses NLog logging.

In Debug mode everything works fine, every projects logs to the specified log file successfully. I use async file target.

In production mode I have a Windows Service that hosts the above WCF Service. This Windows Service contains the NLog package too.

After I install my Windows service I see only log messages from Windows Service and not from the WCF Service and the other class libraries.

How can I receive log messages to file from WCF Service after it's hosted by a Windows Service?

Thank you!

Comment: Look at the log message of the Windows service to see if there is an error message.

Comment: No, there are no error, I see only my debug messages (from the Windows Service). The other projects not produces any logs.

Comment: See if the answers in the link can help you : [Logging Events in a Windows Service Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8160277/logging-events-in-a-windows-service-program) .